# How to use ## in a macro?

Tags: c, macros

Here is a simple demo. But Xcode shows me the error 'pasting formed '->client_port', an invalid preprocessing token
expanded from macro 'PARSE_COLUMN'
cfg->##column = value'

I just want to set value for my struct quickly, and what is the problem with 'cfg->##column = value'

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PARSE_COLUMN( column, value ) \
    printf("parse column:%s\n",#column);\
    cfg->##column = value

typedef struct {
    int client_port;
} server_config;

int main(void) {
    server_config *cfg = new server_config;
    PARSE_COLUMN(client_port,123);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `cfg->##column` to mean? The `##` (token concatenation) seems meaningless to me. Did you just mean `cfg->column`?

Comment: Note that `new server_config` is a syntax error in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`##` is used to concatenate two valid pre-processor tokens into a single one. `cfg->` is not a valid pre-processor token, but rather `cfg`. Therefore you get a compiler error.

In this case you can simply drop the `##` and it will work: `cfg->column = value`.

Please note that macros like these are usually bad practice and functions are preferable.

Answer (score 6):

`##` is used to concatenate two macro arguments, for example `column##value` would be exchanged with `client_port123` in the code above.

You don't need to use it here, you can just write `cfg->column = value`.

Answer (score 0):

**##** is used to split tokens, then concatenate them.

Example:

```
#define A1(name, type)  type name_##type##_type
#define A2(name, type)  type name##_##type##_type

A1(a1, int);  /*  int name_int_type; */
A2(a1, int);  /*  int a1_int_type;   */
```

In macro A1, name_##type##_type is split into 3 parts: {**name_**, **type**, **_type**}, only part 2 **type** is a valid argument and can be replaced.

In macro A2, name##_##type##_type is split into 4 parts: {**name**, **_**, **type**, **_type**}, both part 1 **name** and part 3 **type** are valid arguments and can be replaced.